# Admob Banner below a FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I am creating an admob banner in my existing project. Inside a relative Layout, I am calling a FrameLayout and below the code for admob banner. But the problem is that Admob banner is displaying above the framelayout content.

My XML Code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
        ads:background="@color/theme_ads"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: layout]

As per the admob policy we should not place ads above content. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set your `FrameLayout` above `AdView`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap by another RelativeLayout;

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_rel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
            ads:background="@color/theme_ads"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```